# How to debug the Python error "IndexError: list index out of range, line X"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to programming. For an academic assignment we are to make a game that rolls 5 random dice, displays them, and then checks each one against the other to see if they match, then it adds up how many 'of a kind' the player and computer has and whoever has more wins.  I am currently just trying to get the player side to work, it generates the numbers and then displays them but during the checking I get an index out of range error when it checks the outer loop die to the inner loop dice

I've been racking my brain and changing stuff but since I'm new there could be more errors in there I'm not seeing, here is the code in Python 3.6.2:

```
import random

playerDice = [random.randint(1,6),random.randint(1,6),random.randint(1,6),random.randint(1,6),random.randint(1,6)]
compDice = [random.randint(1,6),random.randint(1,6),random.randint(1,6),random.randint(1,6),random.randint(1,6)]
match = 0
compmatch = 0

#print player dice
print("You rolled: ",end=" ")
a = 0
while a < len(playerDice):
        print(str(playerDice[a]) + ", ",end=" ")
        a = a + 1

#player check matches
i = 0
while i < len(playerDice):

        j = i + 1
        if playerDice[i] == playerDice[j]:
                match = match + 1

        while playerDice[i] != playerDice[j]:
                j = j + 1
                if playerDice[i] == playerDice[j]:
                        match = match + 1

i = i + 1

print("Player has: " + str(match + 1) + " of a kind.")
```

Comment: Your error is very simple to observe, say playerDice = 15, then inside your loop while i varies from 0 to 14 and is correct, but instead j varies from 1 to 15, and when accessing playerDice [j] = playerDice [15] will be out of the proper indices.

Comment: Note that `match = sum(1 for a,b in itertools.product(playerDice, repeat=2) if a==b)` is equivalent to your player check matches section.

Comment: And your print statement could be `print(f"You rolled {', '.join(map(str, playerDice))}")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
while playerDice[i] != playerDice[j]:
        j = j + 1
        if playerDice[i] == playerDice[j]:
            match = match + 1
```

If no elements match, `j` will eventually go out of bounds.

Comment: The problem could be in the next `while` loop, too.

Comment: Actually I think you're right.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: It'll also break in this loop `while playerDice[i] != playerDice[j]` assuming there are no matches in the set.  `j` will continue to increase until there is an index out of bounds exception.

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone!  I got it to quit throwing errors except when array elements 3 and 4(the last 2) match so I didn't fix it but it's working a little better, I will repost a revised question to see if we can get it to work 100%